# Gravity simulator, collision detection, vectors

Tags: c, vector, collision-detection

Im creating a gravity simulator using Vector manipulation and the gravitational constant.
I have defined 2 structs for the bodies.

```
typedef struct {
    double vector[3];
} Vector;

typedef struct {
    Vector colour;
    double mass;
    double radius;
    Vector position;
    Vector velocity;
    Vector accel;
} Object;
```

I have many vector-arithmetic functions including:

```
Vector VectorUnit(Vector a) {

Vector b;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < VECTOR_DIM; i++)
    b.vector[i] = (a.vector[i]) / (VectorMag(a));

return (b);
}
```

When I run the internals of the function, it compiles fine. Though when I explicitly call the function VectorUnit() using any vector quantity it claims a "conflicting type" error..

```
GRAV.c:463:8: error: conflicting types for ‘VectorUnit’
 Vector VectorUnit(Vector a)
    ^
GRAV.c:341:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘VectorUnit’ was here
   VectorUnit(bodies[j].position);
```

What issue is it having with a function call such as VectorUnit(bodies[j].position);
When as mentioned, using the internals of my function compile flawlessly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling functions without declaring them first. This is illegal since C99. In C89 it meant to implicitly declare the function as returning `int`.

You need to provide prototypes for your functions before they are called , e.g. have a header file with:

```
Vector VectorUnit(Vector a);
```

or if that function only appears in one `.c` file, have a declaration near the top of the file:

```
static Vector VectorUnit(Vector a);
```

or place your functions in a different order so that `VectorUnit`'s body comes before any function that calls it.